# How can I get the atoi() function to work on a string?

Tags: c++, string, itoa

```
int p; long unsigned int z;
while (i <= x.length())
{
    const int a = x.length();
    char* b;
    b = x.substr(sizeof(a) - i, 1);
    p = atoi(b);
    z = (z + p + 3) * 3;
    i++;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Anthony\Downloads\pack1.cpp|77|error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'char*' in assignment|
```

I'm trying to go down backwards through 'x' and write each ascii code down as I go. The formula at the bottom is a hash. 'x' is a filename. I'll be unhashing it later. I need to run it through atoi().

Please help, as I do not know what to do. Everything else in the program is running fine, but as for this I'm a bit unsettled at the truthiness that this might be impossible. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and perhaps how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
 now.  The title mentions `itoa()`; the code uses `atoi()` and not `itoa()`?  Which is what you intend?  Where are `p` and `z` defined?

Comment: aslo why char pointer and why not just have char?

Comment: `sizeof(a)` certainly doesn't belong in this *at all*. The implementation octet count of an `int` should have nothing to do with this.

Comment: I used another answer here and it just gave me errors in my header. I did look around a bit before I asked.

Comment: `(const char)b=x.substr(x.length()-i,1).c_str();`

this makes it ask for an lvalue as the left operand. help?

Comment: @thexiv You could also just pass the result of `x.substr(x.length()-i,1).c_str()` to `atoi` directly, IE `atoi(x.substr(x.length()-i,1).c_str())`, since the intermediate variable is just adding problems.

Comment: @user3690202 that's a dangerous suggestion, because you'll be keeping a pointer to the internals of a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

```
int p; long unsigned int z;
while (i <= x.length())
{
  const int a = x.length();
  string b;
  b = x.substr(sizeof(a) - i, 1);
  p = atoi(b.c_str());
  z = (z + p + 3) * 3;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the way to get atoi to take bits of a string! There I said it right! W00t

Comment: you answered the wrong question he wants ATOI not ITOA.

Comment: @Bot - he originally asked about itoa. So it helps if he actually asks about what he wants. 2nd: try add a .c_str() to the end of your substr() line. I suspect that substr() returns a basic_string and not a char*

Comment: why don't you still change it?

Comment: ` int i=1;
            for (i=0;i>=x.length();i++) {
            const char * b=x.c_str();
            const char * c=b[i];
            p=atoi(c);
            z=(z+p+3)*3;
            i++;
            }'
this is what I have now, to make it clearer.

Comment: @thexiv - Either way is pretty unclear, in my opinion. Plus, i'm pretty sure that the line "const char* c = b[i];" is just plain wrong. In either case, this answer is correct - you were missing the c_str() call.

Comment: You do a `c_str()` on a temporary, so `atoi(b)` is UB.

Comment: With intermediate `b`, you have Undefined Behaviour as lifetime of the temporary ends once `b` is set (so `b` contains garbage at the next line (but the garbage may be correct)). With one line, you don't have UB. The safer way would be to use variable for the `substr` result.

Comment: @user3690202: I have prepared for you an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed9a3babbd7b4f30) which shows the UB

Comment: @Jarod42 Apologies for my arrogant comment - you are completely right. substr() returns a basic_string, which gets destroyed after the call to c_str() which, as you rightly point out, leads to a dangling pointer. Silly me for not seeing that.

Comment: @user3690202: Now you may fix your answer.